# what is personality view?

Tags: theravada, vipassana

inner conversation of mind has reduced now.after a period of had stopped during meditation.is it due to Samadhi which achieved?And what is personality view?

Comment: Maybe related: [What are examples of identity-view?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/5862/254)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner conversation will greatly decrease in the second jhana, I'm happy you have experienced this. Yes, this is a development of Samadhi and you are on the right track. A lack of personality view basically speaking, means that you know deeply within yourself that you are simply body, feeling, mental formation, consciousness and perception. That's all, no matter how hard you look that's all you can find. and that's fine. The more developed Samadhi becomes the more the concept of personality fades. It must fade for Samadhi to arise. Keep in mind that until fully awakened you will still have a concept of personality, you need one to survive, however and any time you can turn inwards and try to look for the self or personality and find nothing, it is a very pleasant and peaceful feeling. In that moment you understand that you are everything and nothing simulatiously and nothing can touch you. The fully awakened arahant would reside continuously in this nothingness of self which would, unless he/she retreated to a forest for the lifetime, would find existing in society quite difficult. This is the final fetter of conceit the Buddha talks about. Furthermore, when one understands how personality and personality traits occur one understands them as impermanent, unsatisfactory and not self. Additionally, this is underscored and affirmed by recollecting past lives and seeing how much of a different person you were depending on different circumstances, this helps you to let go of attachment to the personality traits you have. Everything changes.

Comment: During practice even pain arises, it will goes off by noting .is it due to let go of attachment to the body?Is it non self?

Comment: I can see from another comment that you do vipassana practice. You should be aware that the Buddha did not teach this, it's simply not in the suttas. What is likely happening is that you are remaining mindful of your object and the body is relaxing enough for you to move through the jhanas. The mind settles in second jhana which feels empty and almost non-self, in the third there is very little sense of self. In the fourth personality is essential gone. 'purity of mindfulness due to equanimity'

Comment: If you are experiencing pain in your sitting, try incorporating a hatha yoga routine before sitting. The body must be strong. Letting go of attachment of the body does not cause pain, it causes pleasant feeling and satisfaction.

Answer (score -1):

Personality view is seen things as internal (five aggregate) and external (five aggregate).
You perceive internal as I,me and myself and external as not me, not mine and not myself.

Comment: During vipassana practice what happened to the mind when personality goes off?

Comment: The way I understand it also gradual. At Sotapanna stage the personality view is eradicated. At Anagami stage personal identification  (attachment and aversion to Rupa) with Rupa is  eliminated. At Arhant stage personal identification (to five aggregate) is eradicated.